# reference to xxx is ambiguous

Tags: ios, enums, ambiguous

after update cocoapods version,my project reports the error

reference to 'xxx' is ambiguous(xxx is enum)

find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and delete all but it not work

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your one of the cocoa pod library/framework is linked twice somehow. Reference:- [CocoaPods/issues](http://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3511)

Also cross check if you have imported a header file(which contains `enum`) twice.

Comment: thanks! but it's not work for my project, the project language is oc, but i add use_frameworks! to podfile,so, remove it , will work